# jQuery - detect when 'replace' function performs action

Tags: jquery

I use the jQuery replace function to ensure that users can only enter digits and hyphens into the phone number field (its a private web app, and JS has to be enabled to login).

I want to add a css class (highlight red) to the input for x seconds after the replace function is fired so the user sees visually that the input is rejecting there input.

**How do I add a css class to the input for x seconds after the replace function is activated? (only when a input is actually replaced)**

```
$("#v_phone").bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^\d-]/g,'') ); }
);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(functionThatAddCssClass, delay);` I think this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
$("#v_phone").bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var $this = $(this);
    var currentValue = $this.val();
    var newValue = currentValue.replace(/[^\d-]/g,'');
    if (currentValue != newValue) {
       $this.val(newValue);
       $this.addClass("alert");  // add class
       var x = 5;
       setTimeout(function () {
         $this.removeClass("alert");  // remove class after x seconds
       }, x * 1000);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vXMtG/)**.

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is native JavaScript, not jQuery. You can test the expression first and see if the replace is needed and then fire the class:

```
var reg = /[^\d-]/g;

$("#v_phone").bind('keyup blur',function() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    if( reg.test(this.value) ) {
        $this.addClass('highlight');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.removeClass('highlight');
        },1000); // 1s
        $this.val( this.value.replace(reg,'') );
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HvGnf/